# Cannot install lwp on AUR: GPG key rejected by import screener

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent, aur

I am trying to install a package called "lwp" on the Arch User Repository. It requires the pgp key `4EEDEE4D29DAE8A18CAFDA18BEC621B96C853813`

When I try and import the following key, I get an error:

```
$ gpg --recv 4EEDEE4D29DAE8A18CAFDA18BEC621B96C853813                                                                                                           
gpg: key BEC621B96C853813: 1 bad signature
gpg: key BEC621B96C853813: "Jan Harkes <jaharkes@cs.cmu.edu>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

How can I fix this?